# Cannot ssh to localhost using key

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, openssh

I have set up an ssh key and want to connect to localhost using key only, without password (note: this is just a test; ultimately I want to connect to an internal git server, where the same problem occurs).
Here is the output of **ssh -v localhost**

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/myusername/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 7f:96:64:b2:df:f5:de:e8:af:ff:5d:da:5e:3d:e4:c1
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

I read several posts about similar problems, and checked several tips:

- $HOME directory (700), .ssh (700) and .ssh/* (644, except authorized_keys and id_rsa, which have 600) permissions should be correct
- connecting via password works

Interestingly, my computer explicitly states that it accepts the key:

```
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
```

Edit: corresponding auth.log entries:

```
May 18 16:34:44 desktop-178 sshd[3330]: error: RSA_public_decrypt failed: error:0407006A:lib(4):func(112):reason(106)
May 18 16:34:52 desktop-178 sshd[3330]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 [preauth]
```

However, at the end I'm asked for my password. How do I solve this?

Comment: What shows up in the server sshd logs?

Comment: Added the respective log entries - and a preliminary answer (thanks for the nudge in the right direction). However, if you know more, please post an answer and I gladly accept as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post this as an answer, because it partially solves the problem, but I'm not satisfied because I don't understand what's going wrong.

Found at: https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2009-June/msg03099.html

> If I change the name of the private key to id_rsa.old and then specify
>   it with the -i flag I can then login to the first host.

I can confirm that this works, but this is a nuisance at best, and downright confusing.